# Construct hash dynamically in Ruby

Tags: ruby

I have the following ruby code which creates a hash with specified format:

```
  result.each do |result|
    if domain == 'social'
      hash[result['date']] = {
        'positive' => result['positive'],
        'negative' => result['negative'],
        'declined' => result['declined']
      }
    end

    if domain == 'motivation'
      hash[result['date']] = {
        'high'   => result['high'],
        'medium' => result['medium'],
        'low'    => result['low']
      }
    end
  end
```

Is there any way to remove this duplications and do this in more clean way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe creating the hash for `hash[result['date']]` depending on the domain value?:

```
result.each do |result|
  keys = case domain
         when 'social' then %w[positive negative declined]
         when 'motivation' then %w[high medium low]
         end
  hash[result['date']] = keys.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] = result[e] }
end
```

Or:

```
result.each do |result|
  keys = domain == 'social' ? %w[positive negative declined] : %w[high medium low]
  hash[result['date']] = keys.each_with_object(Hash.new(0)) { |e, h| h[e] = result[e] }
end
```

Comment: or `hash[result['date']] = keys.zip(result.values_at(*keys)).to_h`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`Hash#select`](https://docs.ruby-lang.org/en/2.0.0/Hash.html#method-i-select):

```
social_keys = ['positive', 'negative', 'declined']
hash[result['date']] = result.select {|k, _| social_keys.include? k }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result.each do |result|
  hash[result['date']] = result.slice(
    *case domain
    when "social" then %w[positive negative declined]
    when "motivation" then %w[high medium low]
    end
  )
end
```